# Drawing Cantor Set

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to draw a cantor set in LaTeX and I am having issues doing this. I am trying multiple `\put` commands, but they just go to the right of one another. Does anyone know how to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help have something to start with.

Comment: You should also consider using tikz.

Comment: There is code for the Cantor set on page 336 of the Tikz/PGF manual

Answer (score 10):

Just a try with MetaPost. So late after the question, it is really for the fun: it has been a long, long while since the last time I did some recursive programming :-). (Recursive programming is certainly the best way to tackle this sort of task.)

```
pair v; v = (0, -1cm);

def cantor_set(expr segm, n) =
  draw segm;
  if n>1:  
    cantor_set((point 0 of segm -- point 1/3 of segm) shifted v, n-1); 
    cantor_set((point 2/3 of segm -- point 1 of segm) shifted v, n-1); 
  fi;
enddef;

beginfig(1);
  pickup penrazor rotated 90 scaled .5cm;
  cantor_set(origin -- (12cm, 0), 6);
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

Edit: I've changed the "circle" pen for a "razor" pen, which gives a much better drawing precision.

Comment: +1 I honestly feel that MetaPost is the best tool for this task, especially considering the innate recursion involved.

Comment: @SeanAllred I suppose Asymptote would also do well. I may write an Asymptote version of this program later. But can't tikz do recursion itself?

Comment: Yes, but the overhead doesn't really make sense for a TeX-native solution.

Answer (score 8):

Yes the pgfmanual gives a way in Fractal Decorations but it's more funny to find a personal way. I don't find very pretty the syntax to use with decoration.

The next code gives a macro `\cantor` **without tikz**. The macro needs two arguments : the first one is the step and the second is the length of the line.

To get :

[image]

you need to write :

```
\unitlength=1pt 
\linethickness{3mm} 
\xlen=270pt     
\cantor{1}{270pt}\par
\cantor{2}{270pt}\par
\cantor{3}{270pt}\par
\cantor{4}{270pt}\par
\cantor{5}{270pt}\par
\cantor{6}{270pt}
```

Here the complete code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fp}
\newcount\cnt \cnt=1 
\newcount\ccnt \ccnt=0
\newdimen\xpos  
\newdimen\xlen 
\newcount\cnti   
\makeatletter

\def\onestep#1{\advance\ccnt by1 }  
%%%%%%%%%%%% main macro %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% get a string composed with 0 and  1.  If 1 a line is drawn.
% The string  is stored in \tmp
% the length of the string is  stored in \ccnt
\def\scan#1#2\end{% 
\def\aux{#1}% 
\ifx\aux\empty 
\else 
  \ifnum #1=1 
    \ifnum\ccnt=0  \def\tmp{101}%
    \else
       \expandafter\def\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\tmp 101}% 
    \fi
    \else 
       \expandafter\def\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\tmp 000}%
  \fi
  \def\aux{#2}% 
  \onestep{#1}% 
  \ifx\aux\empty  
  \else 
     \scan#2\end 
  \fi
\fi
\gdef\compteur{\the\ccnt}% 
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% draw a line %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\scandraw#1#2\end{%
\def\aux{#1}% 
\ifnum #1=1 
     \put(\strip@pt\xpos,0){\line(1,0){\strip@pt\xlen}}%
      \advance\xpos by \xlen 
  \else 
      \advance\xpos by \xlen 
\fi 
\def\aux{#2}% 
\ifx\aux\empty  
\else 
   \scandraw#2\end 
\fi
}%  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
\def\cantor#1#2{% 
\xpos=0pt \xlen=#2 
\noexpand\def\tmp{1} 
\ifnum #1>1    
  \cnti=1
  \loop 
    \ccnt=0
    \expandafter\scan \tmp\end 
    \advance\cnti by 1 %
    \ifnum \cnti<#1
  \repeat
   \FPeval{\tmpxlen}{\strip@pt\xlen/(3*\compteur)}% 
   \xlen=\tmpxlen pt   
\fi
\begin{picture}(0,15)    
 \expandafter\scandraw \tmp\end  
\end{picture}  
}%    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\makeatother
\begin{document} 

\unitlength=1pt 
\linethickness{3mm} 
\xlen=270pt     
\cantor{1}{270pt}\par
\cantor{2}{270pt}\par
\cantor{3}{270pt}\par
\cantor{4}{270pt}\par
\cantor{5}{270pt}\par
\cantor{6}{270pt}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would you label each level E_0, E_1,... on the RHS and 0 and 1 on the top?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my version of the first five rows for the Cantor set:

```
\begin{picture}(1.1,0.40)(-0.1, -0.1)
\put(0.45, 0.27){$S^c = C$}
\put(0, 0){\line(1, 0){1}}
\put(0, -0.025){\line(0, 1){0.025}}
\put(1, -0.025){\line(0, 1){0.025}}
\put(0, -0.05){\small 0}
\put(1, -0.05){\small 1}

\put(0, 0.25){\line(1, 0){1}}

% (0, 2) / 3
\put(0.0000, 0.20){\line(1, 0){0.3333}}
\put(0.6667, 0.20){\line(1, 0){0.3333}}

% (0, 2, 6, 8) / 9
\put(0.0000, 0.15){\line(1, 0){0.1111}}
\put(0.2222, 0.15){\line(1, 0){0.1111}}
\put(0.6667, 0.15){\line(1, 0){0.1111}}
\put(0.8889, 0.15){\line(1, 0){0.1111}}

% (0, 2, 6, 8, 18, 20, 24, 26) / 27
\put(0.0000, 0.10){\line(1, 0){0.037}}
\put(0.0741, 0.10){\line(1, 0){0.037}}
\put(0.2222, 0.10){\line(1, 0){0.037}}
\put(0.2963, 0.10){\line(1, 0){0.037}}
\put(0.6667, 0.10){\line(1, 0){0.037}}
\put(0.7407, 0.10){\line(1, 0){0.037}}
\put(0.8889, 0.10){\line(1, 0){0.037}}
\put(0.9630, 0.10){\line(1, 0){0.037}}

% (0, 2, 6, 8, 18, 20, 24, 26, 54, 56, 60, 62, 72, 74, 78, 80) / 81
\put(0.0000, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.0247, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.0741, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.0988, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.2222, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.2469, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.2963, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.3210, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.6667, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.6914, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.7407, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.7654, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.8889, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.9136, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.9630, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}
\put(0.9877, 0.05){\line(1, 0){0.0123}}

\end{picture}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference, here is a TikZ solution derived from the TikZ/PGF manual:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=Cantor set,line width=3mm]
  \draw (0,0) -- (3,0);
  \draw decorate{ (0,-.5) -- (3,-.5) };
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1) -- (3,-1) }};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1.5) -- (3,-1.5) }}};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2) -- (3,-2) }}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although I would highly recommend using `tikz`, here is an example of using the `\put` command.

The syntax is `\put(x,y){}` where `(x,y)` is the coordinate of the start point, a the object to be placed at this coordinate is passed in as a parameter within the `{}` braces.  Below I specified this object to be a line with the `\line(u,v){n}` command. In this case `(u,v)` is the direction vector of the line and the length of this line is passed in as `n`.

[image]

Here is the code for the above picture. If this does not help, please use this as a start to create a [small piece of code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) the illustrates the problem that you are having.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(2, 2)
\put(0,0){\line(0,1){3}}% Vertical line of length 3 starting at (0,0)
\put(0,2){\line(1,0){1}}% Horizontal line of length 1 starting at (0,2)
\put(0,1){\line(1,0){5}}% Horizontal line of length 5 starting at (0,1)
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it again with `TeX` rules. I gave some thought to code efficiency. I do not use a loop as anyhow it can not decently go very far, if we want to draw something not at the sub-atomic scale...

The code defines a macro `\cantorrule`:  the first parameter is the level (from `0` to `8`; this parameter may be `\count`) the second a total width, the third a height (no depth parameter).

[image: cantor trickle down]

Code needs `e-TeX` (`etex`, `pdftex` on modern installations, etc..)

```
% first, commented-out, this method which is nice and elegant but 
% not very efficient
% \def\1{\noexpand\1\noexpand\0\noexpand\1}
% \def\0{\noexpand\0\noexpand\0\noexpand\0}
% \def\cantor     {\1}
% \edef\cantori   {\cantor}   % 3
% \edef\cantorii  {\cantori}  % 9
% \edef\cantoriii {\cantorii} % 27
% \edef\cantoriv  {\cantoriii} % 81
% \edef\cantorv   {\cantoriv} % 243
% \edef\cantorvi  {\cantorv}  % 729
% \edef\cantorvii {\cantorvi} % 2187 % already very large-> tiny dimensions

% furthermore in the sequel we avoid sequences of  \0 we prefer  
% \0{j} with j an integer
\newtoks\zerotoks
\newtoks\cantortoks

\def\cantor {\1} % 1
\cantortoks {\1}
\zerotoks   {\0{1}}

% we could do a loop, but what's the point as for example 
% 3^10 is already 59049 and that will make truly tiny distances...

\edef\cantori {\the\cantortoks\the\zerotoks\the\cantortoks}
\cantortoks \expandafter{\cantori}
\zerotoks   {\0{3}}

\edef\cantorii {\the\cantortoks\the\zerotoks\the\cantortoks}
\cantortoks \expandafter{\cantorii}
\zerotoks   {\0{9}}

\edef\cantoriii {\the\cantortoks\the\zerotoks\the\cantortoks}
\cantortoks \expandafter{\cantoriii}
\zerotoks   {\0{27}}

\edef\cantoriv {\the\cantortoks\the\zerotoks\the\cantortoks}
\cantortoks \expandafter{\cantoriv}
\zerotoks   {\0{81}}

\edef\cantorv {\the\cantortoks\the\zerotoks\the\cantortoks}
\cantortoks \expandafter{\cantorv}
\zerotoks   {\0{243}}

\edef\cantorvi {\the\cantortoks\the\zerotoks\the\cantortoks}
\cantortoks \expandafter{\cantorvi}
\zerotoks   {\0{729}}

\edef\cantorvii {\the\cantortoks\the\zerotoks\the\cantortoks}
\cantortoks \expandafter{\cantorvii}
\zerotoks   {\0{2187}}

\edef\cantorviii {\the\cantortoks\the\zerotoks\the\cantortoks}

% does not make much sense to go any further, already \cantorviii has
% subdivisions of length 1/6561 of the total width
% \cantortoks \expandafter{\cantorvii}
% \zerotoks   {\0{6561}}

\def\cantorrule #1#2#3{% #1=0,1,2,..,7, 8; #2=width; #3=height
    \leavevmode
    \begingroup
       \edef\x{\the\numexpr \dimexpr#2\relax/\ifcase \numexpr #1\relax
                                  1\or 3\or 9\or 27\or 81\or 243
                                  \or 729\or 2187\or 6561\else 1\fi\relax}%
       \def\1{\vrule height \dimexpr #3\relax 
                     width \dimexpr \x sp\relax
                     depth 0pt }%
       \def\0##1{\kern \dimexpr \numexpr ##1*\x sp\relax }%
       \hbox{\csname cantor\romannumeral#1\endcsname}%
% to allow #1 to be an infix expression like 2+3 or 7-4 one may use rather
%       \hbox{\csname cantor\romannumeral\numexpr #1\endcsname}%
     \endgroup
}

\offinterlineskip
\noindent\cantorrule {0}{\hsize}{2cm}\par
\noindent\cantorrule {1}{\hsize}{2cm}\par
\noindent\cantorrule {2}{\hsize}{2cm}\par
\noindent\cantorrule {3}{\hsize}{2cm}\par
\noindent\cantorrule {4}{\hsize}{2cm}\par
\noindent\cantorrule {5}{\hsize}{2cm}\par
\noindent\cantorrule {6}{\hsize}{2cm}\par
\noindent\cantorrule {7}{\hsize}{2cm}\par
\noindent\cantorrule {8}{\hsize}{2cm}\par % has 2^8 = 256 little rules

\nopagenumbers

\bye
```